# Why curl http://hostip:81 on the current host, and dnat rules are set, will not go to the lo device

Tags: docker, networking

`docker run -p 81:80 --name nginx1 -d nginx:1.18.0`  start a container.

On the current host curl http://127.0.0.1:81 , use tcpdump to capture data on the lo device.
But on the current host curl http://hostip:81 , no data can be captured on the lo device with tcpdump. hostip is the current host ip.

Please  tell me why curl http://hostip:81 on the current host, , will not go to the lo device

Answer (score 0):

> Please tell me why curl `http://hostip:81` on the current host will not go to the `lo` device

Because the request is hitting a netfilter rule in the `nat` table that looks something like this:

```
-A DOCKER ! -i docker0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 81 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.2:80
```

And that address is reachable via the `docker0` interface, so that's where you'll see the traffic (on port 80, because of the NAT):

```
$ tcpdump -nn -i docker0 port 80
10:49:38.088091 IP 192.168.1.200.42652 > 172.17.0.2.80: Flags [S], seq 410820484, win 65495, options [mss 65495,sackOK,TS val 3642474815 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
10:49:38.088113 IP 172.17.0.2.80 > 192.168.1.200.42652: Flags [S.], seq 2406735006, ack 410820485, win 65160, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 2896225101 ecr 3642474815,nop,wscale 7], length 0
10:49:38.088122 IP 192.168.1.200.42652 > 172.17.0.2.80: Flags [.], ack 1, win 512, options [nop,nop,TS val 3642474815 ecr 2896225101], length 0
.
.
.
```

---

The reason traffic to `127.0.0.1` behaves differently is because traffic from `127.0.0.1` (your source address when making these connections) requires special handling -- because the source address is useless for replies, these packets are generally discarding by the routing system.

To handle this situation, Docker starts up a proxy on your system that listens on port 81 and proxies those requests to your container.

So:

- Requests to 127.0.0.1 are handled by the proxy
- Other requests are handled by the NAT rules

Comment: Thanks, what I'm even more curious about is why curl http://hostip:81 Will match dnat to docker0 instead of first arriving at lo. however http://127.0.0.1:81 It will go to the lo device. I used to think curl http://hostip:81 And curl http://127.0.0.1:81 The effect is the same. How does the underlying system determine.

Comment: I've updated the answer to address your comment.